# ASP.NET Treeview - Add Node through Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, treeview

NET Treeview Control, and I was wondering if it's possible to dynamically add child nodes using Javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.  You'll probably have to use the Telerik Rad Ajax TreeView Control to do that.  Generally if the control doesn't have "Ajax" in the name there isn't going to be much you can do with it in javascript, unless it's a standard html control.

Other option is to go completely client side with the treeview and use something like jQuery UI or YUI.

If you just want to update the tree without a postback you could use an Update Panel

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I ended up doing a custom control using ajax.